# Obtener resultado booleano de la búsqueda en la tabla (datatable.net)

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

Tengo una búsqueda en una tabla que utiliza el plugin de [datatables.net](https://datatables.net/).
este es el código el cual funciona correctamente:

```
let bc_reader = $('#read-bar-code');
let value = bc_reader.val();
let target = bc_reader.attr("data-target");
let table = $(target).DataTable();
let result1 = table.search(value, false, true);
let result2 = table.draw();
console.log(result1, result2);
```

el problema esta que `result1`, `result2` me salen como objetos con múltiples propiedades y no logro encontrar documentación canónica o la manera de retribuir un valor booleano en el caso de encontrar o no resultados o documentación que indique que propiedad contiene el resultado.

**Resultado de la consola javascript:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo esperado seria:

```
console.log(result1) //true: para búsqueda efectiva || false: para no encontró nada.
```

**El objetivo evaluar el resultado de la búsqueda para emitir un sonido de error en caso de que no encuentre nada.**

```
if(!result1){
    window.errorBuzzer();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la única forma que encontré para realizar esto fue implementando un coteo de filas:

```
let result = table.rows({search: 'applied'}).count();
if (result < 1) {
      window.errorBuzzer();
}
```

que dando de esta forma; creo que no es la mejor pero es funcional; si alguien tiene algo mas que agregar es libre de comentar o agregar su respuesta.